# Java duplicate character in string issue

Tags: java, string, substring

I have an assignment for school in which I need to make a function that takes in a string and a letter. It then duplicates the letter in the string and returns it. For example, if I call the function like this
`System.out.println(duplicate("hello world", "l"));`, it should output hellllo worlld. When I do make this call however, the code instead outputs hellllo wlorld. Here is my code:

```
  public static String duplicate(String s, String letter){
    String rv = s;
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
      String a = s.substring(i,i+1);
      if (letter.compareTo(a) == 0){
        rv = rv.substring(0, i) + a + rv.substring(i);
      }
    }
    return rv;
  }
```

Comment: Personally, I'd use something like a `StringBuilder` to create the new `String`

Comment: Great suggestion @MadProgrammer, you would be able to insert after a character at a given index.

Comment: @MadProgrammer unfortunatley, I am not able to use stringbuilder for this assignment. i can only use compareTo, substring, length, and indexOf

Comment: Instead of `letter.compareTo(a) == 0` why not compare `s.charAt(i) == letter` where `letter` is of type char. It doesn't make much sense to use `s.substring(i, i + 1) where you can get the character available, unless you *need* to use string.

Comment: @Jason the assingment dictates that we must use string

Comment: Try to run it step by step, or print some relevant values in each iteration. You'll see when it finds the l in "world" the substrings that you use to create the string with the duplicate letter are not correct. At that point `rv.substring(0, i)` returns "Hellllo W" and `rv.substring(i);` returns "orld", hence why it inserts the character in that position. Take into account that depending on where you insert the duplicate, when you add letters the counter of the loop won't be pointing at the same character and the length of the string will have changed.

Comment: One problem I'm seeing is that you use the same index (`i`) for both `s` and `rv`.  Once you added a new character to `rv` the indexes get shifted by one.  You'll need to find some other way to build the string you want to return.

Comment: @Jason Well, essentially, I'd just append each character as needed, but yes, you could insert a character at a given index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a really quick desk check will highlight the underlying issue...

```
+----+---+----+
|  i | a | rv |
+----+---+----+
| 00 | h |  h |
| 01 | e |  e |
| 02 | l |  l |
| 03 | l |  l |
| 04 | o |  l |
| 05 |   |  l |
| 06 | w |  o |
| 07 | o |    |
| 08 | r |  w |
| 09 | l |  o |
| 10 | d |  o |
+----+---+----+
```

The problem is, the "insert" point is not been updated correctly, instead of offsetting the location by the number of changes that have already been made, you're simply continuing to use the current search index.

My personal preference would be to use a `StringBuilder`, but since you can't do that, a ultra simplistic method which would follow the same general approach anyway, might look something like...

```
public static String duplicate(String s, String letter) {
    String rv = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        String a = s.substring(i, i + 1);
        if (letter.compareTo(a) == 0) {
            rv += a;
        }
        rv += a;
    }
    System.out.println(rv);
    return rv;
}
```

But, if you're not allowed to do that, then you would need to keep track of the "offset" that each new character would need, based on the number of additional characters inserted before it, for example...

```
public static String duplicate(String s, String letter) {
    String rv = s;
    int delta = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        String a = s.substring(i, i + 1);
        if (letter.compareTo(a) == 0) {
            rv = rv.substring(0, i + delta) + a + rv.substring(i + delta);
            delta += 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(rv);
    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you can use indexOf, you don't need to iterate through all the characters in the for loop.

```
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        int index = s.indexOf(letter, i);
        if(index == -1 ) return s;
        s = s.substring(0, index) + letter + s.substring(index);
        i = index + 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering all your constraints, this is what I could come up with.

```java
public static String duplicate(String s, String letter){
    String ans = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        String sub = s.substring(i, i + 1);
        if(sub.compareTo(letter) == 0)
            ans += sub + sub;
        else 
            ans += sub;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

As suggested in the comment section, StringBuilder is the preferred way

```java
public static String duplicate(String s, String letter){
    StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        String sub = s.substring(i, i + 1);
        if(sub.compareTo(letter) == 0)
            ans.append(sub + sub);
        else 
            ans.append(sub);
    }
    return ans.toString();
}
```